# "People in" or "people from"

Tags: grammar

Which Preposition is correct, **from** or **in**?

1- The majority of the **people from** our village migrate for work.

2- The majority of the **people in** our village migrate for work.

3- Some **people in** India works for Facebook.

4- Some **people from** India works for Facebook.

Comment: (Btw, they **work** for Facebook.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone *from* a town (ie born or raised there) will *always* be 'from' that place, no matter where they may move to. So, saying you're *from* somewhere doesn't necessarily mean that you currently live there, but of course, some people could be both *from* a place and *in* that same place! So, they are different, but not mutually exclusive.

In your first two examples, where you are talking about people commuting to work, I think most people would assume that you were talking about people who live there no matter which preposition you used, because there is no logical link between the commutes of people who live in different places.

In your latter examples, you would need to be more clear. You could work for Facebook remotely, so your location wouldn't matter. In this context, people *from* India could include people born there but who now live in other places, so you would need to be specific.